# Specific examples of submodules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I have two issues for which I seek solutions for a long time :

1- Submodules of finitely generated modules need not be finitely generated.

I searched and i found that the submodule $K$ of the finitely generated $R-module$ : $R = \mathbb{Z}[X1, X2, ...]$ consisting of all those polynomials with zero constant term is not finitely generated. The problem is (my problem is) that first I don't see how $R$ is equiped with the structure of a ring (commutative and unitary) and how is it finitely generated as an $R-module$. And secondly I don't understand the structure of $K$ and how is it not finitely generated.

2- Example of a non-free submodule and non-free quotient module of a free module.

And for that second one I don't even have a single clue.

Can anyone help me please. I desperately need some unswer.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is not the correct place to ask when you *desperately* need an answer.

Comment: What I think he wants to say is that you better let words that are emotionally loaded out of your question. ;) It can be that you desperately need an answer, but you don't need to say that. We are not interested in every ones feeling and just want to help you with problems. :)

Comment: I understand. Sorry about that.

Comment: On #1: A ring is always generated as a module over itself by the element $1$.  One definition of a set $S$ ``generating'' a submodule $L$ of $M$ is that the smallest submodule of $M$ that contains $S$ is $L$.  As for $K$, it is generated as an $R$-module by all the $X_n$'s.   You can't use a smaller set to generate $K$ over $R$, according to the above definition.  On #2: Use the example above.  $K$ isn't a free submodule of $R$ (which itself is free of rank $1$ over itself), and $R/K$ isn't free over $R$ either.  There's a lot to digest here, so think on it some more.